# Mount QNAP NAS drive on Ubuntu server

Tags: mount, samba

I'm trying to mount a NAS drive on my Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS server.
I get the error "mount error(2): No such file or directory" even though I can mount the drive in my Windows machine.
I think the problem might be that Ubuntu tries to access the NAS drive as the user 'root'. Can I change that?
I use this syntax for the mount:

`mount -t cifs //<NAS-IP>/Syslog /mnt/syslog_share`

Comment: have you created the directory /mnt/syslog_share and are you using sudo to mount?

Answer (score 1):

> I think the problem might be that Ubuntu tries to access the NAS drive
> as the user 'root'. Can I change that?

By passing the user name the NAS is expecting:

```
mount -t cifs //<NAS-IP>/Syslog /mnt/syslog_share -o username=xxxxx
```

Or passing it "guest" it it allows guest access:

```
mount -t cifs //<NAS-IP>/Syslog /mnt/syslog_share -o guest
```

The other problem you will encounter is wite access to this share.

By default CIFS mounts with owner = root and wite access only to root. If you want for to be able to write to that share yourself you need to tell CIFS that as well. You can for example change owner from root to you with a uid=your-server-user-name:

```
mount -t cifs //<NAS-IP>/Syslog /mnt/syslog_share -o username=xxxxx,uid=your-ubuntu-server-user-name
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked just fine.
On a side note: main problem was that I forgot to allow the file transfer ports in the firewall rules.